# DataTable to list in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have a list

```
Public Class Payment
    Public Property Payments As List(Of PaymentArr)
End Class

Public Class PaymentArr
    Public Property Invoice_Num As String
    Public Property Invoice_Date As String
    Public Property GL_Date As String
End Class
```

and I have a table

```
Inv_Num    Inv_Date    GL_Date
 1          20200606    20200606
 2          20200607    20200607
 3          20200608    20200608
```

I need to convert above table into Payments List, please advise what to do

Comment: Take a look at [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Comment: Start from `table.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(datarow) New PaymentArr With { ..}).ToList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do it:

```
Public Function ConvertTableToList(dt As DataTable) As List(Of PaymentArr)

    Dim payments As New List(Of PaymentArr)
    For Each rw As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim payment As New PaymentArr With
        {
          .Invoice_Num = rw.Item("Inv_Num"),
          .Invoice_Date = rw.Item("Inv_Date"),
          .GL_Date = rw.Item("GL_Date")
        }
        payments.Add(payment)
    Next

    Return payments

End Function
```

Call it as follows:

```
Dim pymnt As New Payment
pymnt.Payments = ConvertTableToList(myDatatable)
```

where myDatatable is the table containing your data

There will be shorter / neater solutions using LINQ but this version should be easy for you to follow